# Memory leak in ODBC32.lib on repeated connect and disconnect operations

Tags: c, windows, winapi, memory-leaks, odbc

I'm seeing a memory leak in `SQLConnect()` on Windows when I call `SQLConnect()` and `SQLDisconnect()` repeatedly.

Here's a very simple program which leaks around 150kB per iteration.

```
int main() {
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    SQLHENV henv;
    SQLHDBC hdbc;
    SQLRETURN retcode;

    // Allocate environment handle  
    retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &henv);

    // Set the ODBC version environment attribute  
    if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
        retcode = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void*)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);

        // Allocate connection handle  
        if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
            retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc);

            // Set login timeout to 5 seconds  
            if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
                SQLSetConnectAttr(hdbc, SQL_LOGIN_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER)5, 0);

                // Connect to data source  
                retcode = SQLConnect(hdbc, (SQLCHAR*) "MySQL", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*) "test", 0, (SQLCHAR*) "test", 0);

                if (retcode == SQL_SUCCESS || retcode == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
                    SQLDisconnect(hdbc);
                }

                SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hdbc);
            }
        }
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv);
    }
}
```

}

Here's a snapshot of the difference in memory allocated before and after the loop showing what's being leaked.
[image: Memory snapshot]

Since `ODBC32.lib` is used by so many people since so many years, I guess it's me doing something wrong (or not doing something that I have to do) that's causing this leak.

A couple of observations that may be interesting:

1. After the first iteration, `hdbc` is the same on all iterations!
2. Instead of doing connect and disconnect in the same loop, if I put
   the handles in an array and disconnect/free them later, I see that
   there's much less leak. Also `hdbc` is different in each iteration.

Do you see anything in the code above that may be causing this leak? I have read the documentation for all the functions I'm using and I couldn't find anything obvious.

Comment: Move each free outside of the if cases so that they are on the same level as the SQLAllocHandle and guard them with a NULL check. Also try to initialize both henv and hdbc to NULL.

Comment: @JohanBregell I tried that already. It doesn't change the behavior. I think the problem is that the handle allocated by `SQLAllocHandle()` always the same and somehow it doesn't work well with `SQLConnect` and `SQLDisconnect`.

Comment: What specific versions of Windows and `ODBC32.lib` are you looking at?  Are you certain that all MS patches have been applied?

Comment: @TallTed So far I have tested it on Windows 10, Server 2012 and Server 2016. All Windows updates have been installed. The version of `odbc32.dll` is 10.0.17134.1. Do you know how I can find out the version of `odbc32.lib`?

Comment: `odbc32.lib` is generally installed as part of a Windows SDK, and gets updated by a Microsoft (but not Windows) update. Have you checked the usual `Properties` dialog for that file version? You might also try looking at it through [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)... (I notice that your report was written about `odbc32.lib` but your screenshot shows `odbc32.dll` so maybe the latter is where you think this leak is found?)

Comment: I think that this might be dependent on the ODBC driver and its configuration.  Just for the record, I found the following link https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/119/Q119150; even though it's so old, it might still be interesting to some.